# Spring Criteria where vs and - what is the difference?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

What is the difference between above mentioned methods which of following code fragments is correct:

**where**

```
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
criteria.where("name").is("Jon")
        .where("age").is(20)
        .where("gender").is("male");
```

**and**

```
Criteria criteria = new Criteria()
criteria.and("name").is("Jon")
        .and("age").is(20)
        .and("gender").is("male");
```

**mixed**

```
Criteria criteria = new Criteria()
criteria.where("name").is("Jon")
        .and("age").is(20)
        .and("gender").is("male");
```

Which one should be used to append new conditions?

eg.

```
Criteria criteria = new Criteria()
criteria.where("name").is("Jon")
        .and("age").is(20);
if(isComplex)
        criteria.and("gender").is("male");
```

Please give me some examples when they should be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you see from the backend implementation of both these two function as fellow

```
/**
     * Static factory method to create a Criteria using the provided key
     * 
     * @param key
     * @return
     */
    public static Criteria where(String key) {
        return new Criteria(key);
    }

    /**
     * Static factory method to create a Criteria using the provided key
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public Criteria and(String key) {
        return new Criteria(this.criteriaChain, key);
    }
```

So in and Method Criteria class uses its data member criteriaChain which is a List...So you can associate list of Criteria with and method but not with where.

And here is the Criteria Class (Partial)

```
public class Criteria implements CriteriaDefinition {

    /**
     * Custom "not-null" object as we have to be able to work with {@literal null} values as well.
     */
    private static final Object NOT_SET = new Object();

    private String key;
    private List<Criteria> criteriaChain;  \\This datamember is used when you are using and
```